# Preparation in sports?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

What was wrong please with the question on sports preparation? https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/28474/in-top-level-physical-sports-do-players-analyse-opponents-games-strategise-e

Is there a problem if I ask for a specific sport say basketball, boxing or [golf](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/327355/whats-the-term-for-those-sports-games-that-dont-really-have-offense-or-defense)?

Answer (score 4):

The question would be closed for any one of the reasons below.

1. It is hard to understand, rambling, and isn't written well.  A good question will ask a specific question, provide some background information, but is fundamentally about the question - if you get to the question after four paragraphs, you're probably headed in the wrong direction.
2. It is too broad.  Asking a question about *every* sport, when they're quite different, is not a good idea; the idea is questions should have *one* correct answer ideally.  Some sites allow this to be slightly different ([Law.se](https://law.stackexchange.com) for example allows an answer per jurisdiction), but even then it's still expected that the question is relatively tight.  This question even on one sport isn't really that.
3. The question will elicit an opinion-based answer for the most part.  Maybe we can find evidence of one or two sports players who prepare in a certain way; but for the most part, it's going to be not directly knowable.
4. The question won't have a single answer even if all of the above is met; each player does things differently.  As such, the answer seems obvious - "each player does things differently" - but also not useful.
5. The question does not show any evidence of research.  You post a bunch of links about chess - not a sport, at least as we define it - and then ask about sports; but it's clear that you're coming from a chess perspective.  You need to have some *sports* background to ask a *sports* question - not saying you need to be an expert, but perhaps at least look at some famous athletes and see what you find there?  Then the question can be better written, because you can use them as your examples (Lebron/Kobe/MJ for basketball, etc.), and your question can be more focused.

Honestly, your questions are a much better fit for reddit than here; this isn't a discussion forum.  I'd recommend going to reddit and asking there, see what people say, and start a discussion.  Here we don't do that.